# How do I implement simple copy/paste functionality in an mfc CListCtrl?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Is this really the easiest way to do this?

http://simplesamples.info/MFC/Clipboard.php

Comment: My source is a CListCtrl. I want to paste to a simple texteditor. I don`t expect any particular formatting.

Comment: [user1721368](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1721368) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66692037) saying "The simplesamples link in the question seems to be broken.  I *think* it was meant to refer to this:  http://simplesamples.info/MFC/Clipboard.aspx"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is your list the source or destination? Do you need to copy/paste to or from something else like Excel? Do you expect some specific formatting? It all depends.

**Edit**:
If you are moving things out to simple text, your link looks good. See [Clipboard: Using the Windows Clipboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/80db3kax.aspx) too.